# Videojs VAST ads in between each video on a playlist

Tags: javascript, html, youtube, html5-video, video.js

I'm using Video.js and trying to figure out a way to create a playlist that plays videos with a VAST ad in between each video on the playlist.

I've identified these plugins to help:

https://github.com/tim-peterson/videojs-playlist

https://github.com/PetroFrolov/vast-video-js

Also, I would love to slide YouTube videos in there as the "source" using this:

(link removed) - eXon plugin

Anyone have any ideas on the tweaks needed for this?

Answer (score 1):

I wonder have you tried to add ads into playlist with some to be implemented later "ad" attribute?

In this way, actual playlist will be transformed from original.